# .remove(":contains()") not working

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have a `input field` where value is equal to the `id`'s and a `button`. When that `button` is triggered I want to **remove** the `id` in the input field also the button where the `value` `is equal` to the data stored in the input field or the id. Here http://jsfiddle.net/leonardeveloper/hcfzL/3/

HTML:

```
<form id="materialForm" action="#" method="post">
    <input id="materials" type="text" name="materials" value="1,2,3" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
<div id="display">
    <button class="removes" value="1">x</button>
    <button class="removes" value="2">x</button>
    <button class="removes" value="3">x</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.removes', function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    alert(id);
    $('#materials').remove(":contains('" + id + "')");
    $('#display').remove(":contains('" + id + "')");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: There's no AJAX in your question, I removed those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).on('click','.removes',function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $('#materials').val(function(){
        var value = this.value, array = value.split(',');
        var idx = $.inArray(id, array);
        if(idx >=0 ){
            array.splice(idx, 1)
            value = array.join(',')
        }
        return value;
    })
    $(this).remove();
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RqwsP/)

Comment: what is the .splice function?

Comment: it is an array function to remove/replace elements from an array using index

Comment: It replaces a portion of an array with new elements. If you don't supply the new elements, it just removes the specified portion.

Comment: @ArunPJohny why is it that the buttons only disappear? coz in my real project i have a materials name some sort of that and i want to remove also the container how could i do that?

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza you need to share the html with the container also

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza looks like you want to remove the `td` then use `$(this).closest('td').remove()`

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').remove()` `tr` actually well then thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 2):

`.remove()` is for removing DOM elements, not text from values. And it removes the element it's applied to, not elements that are contained within it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.removes', function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    alert(id);
    var materials = $('#materials').val().split(',');
    materials = materials.filter(function(e) {
        return e != id;
    });
    $('#materials').val(materials.join(','));
    $(this).remove();
    return false;
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/hcfzL/5/)

Comment: why is it the only the button disappear? how can i do that here is my actual code.it call using jquery http://codejaw.com/33j0c

Comment: Use DOM traversal methods to target the element you really want to remove, relative to `$(this).`

Answer (score 1):

The `:contains` selector is for selecting DOM nodes that *contain* other DOM nodes. In your case you look to be selecting input elements which have a particular string in their value.

You should probably use `.filter` to filter to select the input elements that match the filter.